# При попытке использовать Dmatrix ошибка: "AttributeError: 'DMatrix' object has no attribute 'items'"

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, xgboost

При попытке использовать Dmatrix в xgboost.cv:

```
params = {
    'num_boost_round': 500,
    'max_depth': 4,
    'min_child_weight': 2,
    'subsample': 0.8,
    'colsample_bytree': 0.5,
    'eta':0.05}


X_train = np.random.random(size=(100, 1000))
y_train = np.random.random(size=(100, 1))
dtrain = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train,label = y_train)
rescv = xgboost.cv(dtrain,params,nfold=5,metrics = 'precision',early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

Выводит ошибку:

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-86-96544cdc772c> in <module>()
     10 y_train = np.random.random(size=(100, 1))
     11 dtrain = xgboost.DMatrix(X_train,label = y_train)
---> 12 rescv = xgboost.cv(dtrain,params,nfold=5,metrics = 'precision',early_stopping_rounds=20)
     13 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\xgboost\training.pyc in cv(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, nfold, stratified, folds, metrics, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, fpreproc, as_pandas, verbose_eval, show_stdv, seed, callbacks, shuffle)
    401             params['eval_metric'] = _metrics
    402     else:
--> 403         params = dict((k, v) for k, v in params.items())
    404 
    405     if len(metrics) == 0 and 'eval_metric' in params:

AttributeError: 'DMatrix' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже вы перепутали порядок параметров. Лучше явно указывать имена параметров, чтобы избежать подобных ошибок:

```
rescv = xgboost.cv(
  params=params,
  data=dtrain,
  nfold=5,
  metrics='precision',
  early_stopping_rounds=20)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.  rescv = xgboost.cv(params=params, dtrain=dtrain,  nfold=5,  metrics=['f1'], early_stopping_rounds=20)